# How do I add newlines between multiple calls of an API returning JSON?

Tags: api, rust

I'm working on an API wrapper for Etherscan.io. I have the `get_balance()`  working with a few issues:

```
use super::Config;
use hyper::rt::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::{Body, Client};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use serde_json::from_slice;
use std::io::{self, Write};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Account<'a> {
    result: &'a [u8],
}

pub fn get_balance(config: Config) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    let uri = format!(
        "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module={}&action={}&address={}&tag={}&apiKey={}",
        config.module, config.action, config.address, config.tag, config.api_key
    ).parse()
    .unwrap();

    let https = HttpsConnector::new(4).unwrap();
    let client = Client::builder().build::<_, Body>(https);

    client
        .get(uri)
        .and_then(|res| {
            res.into_body().for_each(|chunk| {
                let data: Account = from_slice(&chunk).unwrap();
                io::stdout()
                    .write_all(data.result)
                    .map_err(|e| panic!("Something went wrong!, {}", e))
            })
        }).map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("Error {}", e);
        })
}
```

Right now, I'm using serde_json to deserialize the `result` field in the JSON output from Etherscan's API into an `Account` type variable.

In the binary for this crate, I've read in a file containing a line separated list of Ethereum addresses, and am calling the `get_balance` function on each address. Currently, the output looks like this

```
Grabbing balances..
 2978949000000000000050000000000118989773837777777707832422000000000077725000000000005585715000000000632954201591000000000000039261000000000922242282421612059956805551700000009340396200000000001302155554000000000001024761480000000000000646546600000000025849226140000000173919401191242898017721300000000000282583067321734110921765800000000010664815135755183661247667868029222166231631200777777777719780855300000000020000000000009862760431183982253209705167363654310198841461200000000000422146084184411875600927519797468763322494071578107259000000000000460845548541297500001497258879653777777777097542367974112844500097065356751518011568537848158458245828091288718199214820000000000012229358000000000019172756010000000000818949139302890483000000000000671348000000000000396900000000000000004692796996935622836101639000000000004313773803864317079183499000000000001851446000000292904912031700000000002833822400000000118576145806291502820102991980000000000031095375771474016024005236052920127528866968915028175902833735562412900300
```

As you can see, each balance is printed one after another, with no newline character to separate any of them. Furthermore, the output is quite delayed, as if it's waiting for a buffer to be filled up before writing to the screen. Would this be on account of the fact that the type in use for the call to `write_all` is `&[u8]`?

How do I go about having the output formatted in the manner I'm looking for, i.e with each balance on a newline?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, `Config` is not defined and presumably we need values to run the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `.map()` is what I was looking for:

```
client.get(uri).and_then(|res| {
    res.into_body()
        .for_each(|chunk| {
            let data: Account = from_slice(&chunk).unwrap();
            io::stdout()
                .write_all(data.result)
                .map_err(|e| panic!("Something went wrong!, {}", e))
        }).map(|_| {
            print!("\n");
        })
})
```

Comment: This... doesn't seem like it should work, because `Iterator::for_each` is eager and returns `()`. Is this a different `for_each` method?

Comment: @trentcl pretty sure it's a `Future` or `Stream`.

Comment: Still, this looks really confusing. Why not simply write a `\n` and flush after the first `io::stdout().write_all`?